# What does "Poussent contre l'ivoire un ivoire arrondi." mean?

Tags: sens

> Les joueurs le matin comme après-midi
>   **Poussent contre l'ivoire  un ivoire arrondi.**
>
> Ne criez pas au plagiat! Je viens de détourner un vers de l'abbé
>   Delille, mais je ne le nie guère.

This is from Tristan Derème  "Patachou"

What does  "Poussent contre l'ivoire  un ivoire arrondi." mean?
What is the defference between "l'ivoire" and "un ivoire"?
Please teach me if somebody know the original verse by Jacques Delille.

Answer (score 5):

#### Origin

The original citation is from [Delille - L Homme des champs](https://fr.wikisource.org/wiki/Page:Delille_-_L_Homme_des_champs_1800.djvu/49).

> Là, sur un tapis vert, un essaim étourdi
> Pousse contre l’ivoire un ivoire arrondi ;
> La blouse le reçoit.

---

#### Explanation

The [Gradus](https://books.google.fr/books?id=7zXUSvzDjN0C&pg=PA652&lpg=PA652&dq=L%C3%A0,%20sur%20un%20tapis%20vert%20%5Bbillard%5D%20Pousse%20contre%20l%27ivoire%20%5Bbille%5D%20un%20ivoire%20arrondi%20;%20La%20blouse%20le%20re%C3%A7oit%20(DELILLE%20l%27Homme%20des%20ch.%20I)&source=bl&ots=qj9uDP07LR&sig=cDY2SkTLn-BEQ2THstcxcq-FAaA&hl=fr&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwil6Lf65_fPAhXFPBoKHaXSC14Q6AEIHzAB#v=onepage&q=L%C3%A0%2C%20sur%20un%20tapis%20vert%20%5Bbillard%5D%20Pousse%20contre%20l%27ivoire%20%5Bbille%5D%20un%20ivoire%20arrondi%20%3B%20La%20blouse%20le%20re%C3%A7oit%20(DELILLE%20l%27Homme%20des%20ch.%20I)&f=false) explains the *"tapis vert"* (green carpet) is a billards (or pool or snooker) table.

In [Littré](http://www.littre.org/definition/ivoire) and in [leparisien.sensagen](http://dictionnaire.sensagent.leparisien.fr/ivoire/fr-fr/) it is explained that some expensive billards balls can be in ivory or **of color of ivory**, and there, are called directly in the matter they are made from (or look like).

Moreover, @MakorDal added that *"la blouse"* is "the pocket on a pool table".

---

#### Answer

So, to conclude, this expression means **to play billards/pool game**.

---

**Further research**

The University of Toronto has [one line](http://scans.library.utoronto.ca/pdf/7/16/moliremusicien00cast/moliremusicien00cast.pdf) about it :

> > Pousser contre l'ivoire un ivoire arrondi,
>
> signifiera jouer au billard, si nous en croyons Delille ;

Comment: Also "la blouse" is the pocket on a pool table.

Comment: @MakorDal Thanks, I edited to add your comment

Comment: But still it seems there are two things made of ivory. One is the ball but what is the other one?

Comment: @SimonDéchamps Il se trouve qu'après les boules, les queues peuvent aussi être en partie faites d'ivoire.

Comment: @YohannV. OK merci.

Comment: @SimonDéchamps Je ne suis pas sur de cette dernière hypothèse, j'ai trouvé [ceci](http://operacritiques.free.fr/css/index.php?2016/04/25/2795-entendre-parler-la-musique) qui me fait croire à une expression, mais impossible de trouver une explication.

Comment: @YohannV. Dans ton lien, ça semble être une paraphrase pour "jouer du piano", vu que les touches ont souvent été en ivoire. Formulation utilisée ici pour dire que la personne ne "joue" pas, mais juste "appuie sur les touches" sans conviction.

Comment: @SimonDéchamps Oui mais si on peut créer des expressions soi-même à la volée ça devient compliqué à expliquer à des étrangers...

Comment: @SimonDéchamps Pour répondre à ta première question - simplement pousser un boule vers les autres.  Mais on peut retrouver aussi l'idée de jouer pour tuer le temps, en "poussant" un boule, plutôt qu'en la frappant, en la jouant,...

Comment: Thank you so much for the  kind answer and many detailed comments that are so helpful for me!!

Comment: @HiroshiInagaki If this answer covers your need, thanks to accept it. ;)

Comment: Note that, contrary to what you can read in these commentaries, "boule" in feminine, so it's "**une** boule", not "**un** boule". (unless you are using the slang denomination for the ass, which is obviously not what we are talking about here)